# Prevent drawing over a child window under WorkerW when wallpaper is changed

Tags: c++, winapi, dwm

after reading this article and trying in c++

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus

I managed to set my window as child of the WorkerW window which draws behind the desktop icons
[image]

but the problem is when user changes to next wallpaper or slideshow happens, I detect the event after the animation has started which changes the wallpaper using a fade animation , a new WorkerW is spawned which draws on top of the existing WorkerW, so is there any way to get the new WorkerW handle to draw behind my window or make my window child of the new WorkerW very fast so that the drawing over my window is not noticeable?

https://youtu.be/N4XC7VLpPi0

:: After applying Lemi's way ->
[image]

[Edit 2 :]

I managed to place my window inside the **SHELLDLL** view and on top of the desktop icons (i.e. the list view) [GLFW30 named one]

[image]

To Reproduce:

1. Get a window handle from any appplication.
2. Open Spy++ and find the window handle of the **SHELLDLL view** and convert it from hex to decimal , and then pass it in the **SetParent**(windowHWND, targetHWND).
3. **SetWindowPos** pass the listView32 window handle as the hwndInsertAfter parameter and then run the program , our current window will get placed below the listview32
   [image]

But sad thing , the listview32 overrides all the background painting by my window and only shows the current windows wallpaper :(

[image]

Comment: ANY solution you come up with is suspect since you are manipulating windows you don't own. But in any case, have you tried moving your window onto the `WorkerW` that hosts the `ShellDLL_DefView`, and then move that window above yours on the z-order with `SetWindowPos()`? Then you wouldn't have to worry about these secondary `WorkerW` windows that are created during wallpaper changes

Comment: i get the first part but the second step i m confused, can u elaborate?

Comment: How to move that behind the icons now ? i set it child of the frame containing the shelldll_DefView

Comment: Did you try [`SetWindowPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos), like I suggested? It can move windows back and forth in z-order.

Comment: Ya that didn't work

Comment: Try creating windows with `WS_EX_LAYERED`. Set the window to a layered window. And use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to set opacity at your window or blend opacity. Make sure your window have a background in registered class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes

Comment: And `SetWindowPos()` is asynchronous when changing the z-order, you need to add `Sleep()`;

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal reproducible sample? I can spend my time on verifying it.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT I'll provide soon as i reach home, i m out of station for a week .

Comment: @Shubhz Don't forget editing the question to provide a minimal reproducible sample. I still focus on solving it.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT ah mb, i ll upload it today wait

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT check i edited the question

Comment: @Shubhz Check if this what you want.: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/ba54a93c5d0de48d77dd07559f6fe779 This is, I will make an answer to explained its details. I just show a orange window for a example, you can change it to a webview2 or webGL window.

Comment: okk i ll check and see